# Active Directory lastLogon only changes after two unsuccessful attempts

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm able to validate a user by forcing a bind on a `DirectoryEntry` object like so:

```
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (var directoryEntry =  new DirectoryEntry("LDAP:" + "//" + server + 
        "/" + containerDistinguishedName,
        domain + @"\" + username, password, 
        AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
    {
        // invoke a bind to the directory entry
        try
        {
            var obj = directoryEntry.NativeObject;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to the previous way I was doing this here:

- [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials doesn't set lastLogon date for
  user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606368/principalcontext-validatecredentials-doesnt-set-lastlogon-date-for-user)

However, I was unable to get that working and I eventually started decompiling some other code which led me to write this.

When a user is validated with this code, the `lastLogon` Active Directory attribute is not set regardless of how many successful validations they go through. One strange feature (which I have specified in the title of this question) is that **two failed attempts and then one successful login** will update the `lastLogon` value in the directory.

If the user fails to login once but then succeeds on the second attempt, the value isn't updated. It's only specifically after two failures that their `lastLogon` attribute updates.

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: How many domain controlers have you got on your domain.

Comment: Just the one. I was digging around and found this quote: "When a concurrent bind is used, the last logon date for the user is not updated in the directory; therefore, the LastLoginDate property cannot be relied on." [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ValidateUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.validateuser.aspx). This explains why the value isn't updated but using `AuthenticationType.ServerBind` still isn't updating the value. The AD is in 2000 mode on Win2003 Server.

Comment: @Codesleuth I'm encountering the same problem. Did you find a solution for it? :)